# VMware key typing is strange in vi

Tags: vmware, vi

I am install VMware station 12 in win7 to run a ubuntu 14.04 LTS server.

When using vi, the key is in chaos.

For example, in insert mode(after I press 'i'), backspace can not delete the character which on left of cursor, instead it left move the cursor.

Sometimes the 'x' can delete the character, sometimes it can not.

Sometimes the enter will replicate all characters

In summary, the behavior of vi is total different than normal linux. How to set this?

I have not install "enhanced keybroad driver", but only vi have this problem.

Comment: Does it work better when you login via SSH (instead of the VMWare console)?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's just normal behaviour which happens because of wrong typing.

The thing with backspace for example is a normal thing, add the following to your .vimrc to solve this:

```
set backspace=indent,eol,start
```